# Excel - Find corresponding values in single formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure how to phrase this hence the vague title.. sorry.

Here's my scenario.

**Data**

Table 1

Col A = Home Team

Col B = Away Team

Col C = Home Score

Col D = Away Score

What I would like to do is get an average of a teams last 3 scores in a single formula.

The issue is the team could appear in either column, home or away.
If the team is Col A - I need the value in Col C. If the team is in Col B - I need the value in Col D.

Any ideas are appreciated. I'm stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for interest, here's a shot at doing it with a single formula

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C1:D7,N(IF({1},LARGE(IF(A2:B7=F2,ROW(A2:B7)*3+COLUMN(A2:B7)),{1,2,3})/3)),
N(IF({1},MOD(LARGE(IF(A2:B7=F2,ROW(A2:B7)*3+COLUMN(A2:B7)),{1,2,3}),3)))))
```

Has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and assumes data starts in column A

[image]

**Edit**

Not necessary to do division just for row so can simplify to

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C1:D7,N(IF({1},LARGE(IF(A2:B7=F2,ROW(A2:B7)),{1,2,3}))),
N(IF({1},MOD(LARGE(IF(A2:B7=F2,ROW(A2:B7)*3+COLUMN(A2:B7)),{1,2,3}),3)))))
```

Comment: Nice formula :) @TomSharpe

Comment: Thanks - it gets the same answer as yours so can't be all bad :-)

Comment: This is great Tom, thank you!
How do I flip it so it reads top down?

In your example the top down answer would be 4. (4,6,2)

Comment: Should be straightforward - just replace LARGE with SMALL in the formula.

Comment: Hey Tom - I've got the following formula and it's not picking up the correct values. Where have I gone wrong?


=AVERAGE(INDEX(BothTotals,N(IF({1},SMALL(IF(BothTeams=B2,ROW(BothTeams)*3+COLUMN(BothTeams)),{1,2,3})/3)),
N(IF({1},MOD(SMALL(IF(BothTeams=B2,ROW(BothTeams)*3+COLUMN(BothTeams)),{1,2,3}),3)))))


Both teams = Sheet 1 $H$6:$I$1944

Both totals = Sheet 1 $J$6:$K$1944

Comment: You'd have to modify the formula if the list doesn't start in column A because it assumes that column(BothTeams) is less than 3. Will try and post something but might not be till later.

Comment: Have got this at the moment but it can be simplified =AVERAGE(INDEX(BothTotals,N(IF({1},SMALL(IF(BothTeams=B2,(ROW(BothTeams)-ROW(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1)))*3+(COLUMN(BothTeams)-COLUMN(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1)))+3),{1,2,3})/3)),
N(IF({1},MOD(SMALL(IF(BothTeams=B2,(ROW(BothTeams)-ROW(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1)))*3+(COLUMN(BothTeams)-COLUMN(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1)))+1),{1,2,3}),3)))))

Comment: You're a legend Tom. That is EXACTLY what I was after. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hey Tom - one last question! How would i invert this so I could get their last 3 conceded? Thanks

Comment: You want the average of the goals scored against them in the last 3 matches? Will have a look tonight football permitting.

Comment: =AVERAGE(INDEX(BothTotals,N(IF({1},SMALL(IF(BothTeams=B2,ROW(BothTeams)-ROW(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1))+1),{1,2,3}))),
N(IF({1},3-MOD(SMALL(IF(BothTeams=B2,(ROW(BothTeams)-ROW(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1)))*3+(COLUMN(BothTeams)-COLUMN(INDEX(BothTeams,1,1)))+1),{1,2,3}),3)))))   :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will be quite a ugly formula but it helps to get what you want, the average of the LAST three scores of a team:

- In this example I have put the search value (Team2) in F9 (used in formulas)
- Create a helper column and put this formula in it and drag it down (we need the rownumber of a hit in our future INDEX formula):

  ```
  =IF(OR(A2=$F$9,B2=$F$9),ROW(A2),"")
  ```

[image]

- Now we need to create a formula that will average the largest 3 numbers

  ```
  =AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:D7,LARGE(E:E,1),MATCH($F$9,INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(E:E,1)&":B"&LARGE(E:E,1)),0)+2),INDEX(A1:D7,LARGE(E:E,2),MATCH($F$9,INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(E:E,2)&":B"&LARGE(E:E,2)),0)+2),INDEX(A1:D7,LARGE(E:E,3),MATCH($F$9,INDIRECT("A"&LARGE(E:E,3)&":B"&LARGE(E:E,3)),0)+2))
  ```

In this case the formula will return 4.33333

There is possibly a better way, however this one works :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COUNTIFS` and `SUMIFS` to make a logical average calculation.

Formula in `H4` below is:

```
=(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,G4)+SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,G4))/(COUNTIFS(B:B,G4)+COUNTIFS(A:A,G4))
```

[image: homeawayteam]

Answer (score 0):

Another use of AVERAGEIFS with INDEX/AGGREGATE.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(E:E, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($2:$999)/((C$2:C$999=I5)+(D$2:D$999=I5)), 3)):F$999, INDEX(C:C, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($2:$999)/((C$2:C$999=I5)+(D$2:D$999=I5)), 3)):D$999, I5)
```

[image]